# Обратный звонок, как организовать смс оповещение на телефон

Tags: joomla, php

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт - агентство праздников на джумле, на нем установлен модуль "обратный звонок". Хотелось бы, чтобы при отправлении запроса на обратный звонок кроме письма на почту приходило и смс уведомление на телефон. Возможно ли как-нибудь дополнить код модуля, чтобы присылались смс на телефон или, может быть, бывают готовые скрипты, которые проделывают это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да конечно, нет проблем вообще. Регистрируешься на http://sms.ru. Заглядываешь в раздел "программистам" и читаешь весь раздел, все подробно описано. Очень понятное и интегрируемое API. Встраивается куда угодно в т.ч. и в joomla. Тарифы на СМС самые дешевые по россии. Работает безотказно. Проверено.

**UPD1:** Пошаговая инструкция:

1) скачиваем файл https://github.com/zelenin/sms_ru/blob/master/src/smsru.php (далее ИС - интегрируемый скрипт)

2) располагаем этот файл в папке со скриптом который отправляет уведомление на почту (ЦС - целевой скрипт)

3)  в ЦС в самом верху вставляем следующий php-код

```
include "smsru.php";
$sms = new \Zelenin\smsru( 'ваш API-код вида d48bcb54-9c2b-97f4-19ed-d2a8c1ceea9b', 'телефон указанный при регистрации', 'пароль от аккаунта на смс.ру' ); Здесь мы инициализировали класс для работы с функциями предоставляемыми API и получили объект $sms с которым и будем работать
```

4) Теперь переходим непосредственно к отправке. Вставляем следующей за отправкой уведомления на почту строкой (в ЦС), код отправляющий смс-уведомление:

```
$result = $sms->sms_send( 'номер(а) на которые отсылается уведомление, через запятую', 'Текст SMS' ); // в result помещается результат смс-рассылки, ее стоимость, если будете отправлять на свой номер то это бесплатно
unset($sms); // освобождаем память
```

5) Все остальные функции можно почитать в документации, там много интересных плюшек кроме отправки, если интересно конечно =)

Comment: Спасибо! Я  пробовала, но дело в том, что я в этом не очень сильна, хотя разбираюсь немного в php. Подскажите, пожалуйста, основные шаги.

Comment: А какой версии Joomla?

Comment: Новая версия, joomla3

Comment: Спасибо, но страница выдает ошибку 404, но теперь хоть что-то стало понятно).

Comment: Вот тут инструкция по привязке API https://github.com/zelenin/sms_ru, все что здесь описывается нужно производить в том файле где отправляется уведомление на почту.

Comment: Таак, в общем где у вас происходит отправка письма, вы знаете?

Comment: Отправка письма, я так полагаю, происходит в файле mod_callback.php, и огромное спасибо за ответ!